# how to solve error problem "AAPT: error: '@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color." in android studio

Tags: java

ERROR: C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\TicTacToe\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:33: AAPT: error: '@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color.

ERROR: C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\TicTacToe\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:61: AAPT: error: '@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color.

ERROR: C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\TicTacToe\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:72: AAPT: error: '@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color.

ERROR: C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\TicTacToe\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:83: AAPT: error: '@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color.

ERROR: C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\TicTacToe\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:102: AAPT: error: '@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color.

ERROR: C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\TicTacToe\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:113: AAPT: error: '@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color.

ERROR: C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\TicTacToe\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:124: AAPT: error: '@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color.

ERROR: C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\TicTacToe\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:143: AAPT: error: '@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color.

ERROR: C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\TicTacToe\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:154: AAPT: error: '@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color.

ERROR: C:\Users\dell\AndroidStudioProjects\TicTacToe\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:165: AAPT: error: '@tools:sample/avatars' is incompatible with attribute src (attr) reference|color.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MondP.png)
android studio project

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).